# Is correct to assign to a variable using && with the same variable in Java?

Tags: java, performance, optimization, boolean

I'm making some changes into an old code than requires maintenance, and I found something like this

```
public boolean aMethod(){
    boolean isValid = true;

    **isValid = isValid &&** executeGetDocs(id.toString(),program().toString(), document.get(name));

  return isValid;
}
```

The method **executeGetDocs** may return true or false.

But I'm not sure if: **isValid = isValid && executeGetDocs ** is correct or is just redundant.

So here I am, can anyone please, give me some explanation about this?

Thanks a lot!

**EDITED**

Whole method:

```
private boolean validateDocs(List<Map<String, Object>> documentsList) {
        boolean isValid = true;
        StringBuilder gradoAntComp = new StringBuilder();
        for (Map<String, Object> document : documentsList) {
            String id = document.get("ID_DOC").toString();
            if (id.equalsIgnoreCase("25")) {
                isValid = getData(id.toString(),program().toString(), document.get(name))
            } else if (id.equalsIgnoreCase("26") ) {
                isValid = isValid && getDocs(id.toString(),program().toString(), document.get(name));
            } 
        }
        return isValid;
    }
```

Comment: Is that the whole code of the method? If it is, it can be reduced to `return executeGetDocs(id.toString(),program().toString(), document.get(name));`

Comment: `**isValid` is not valid Java.

Comment: Title can use some improvement--it doesn't really say anything substantial.

Comment: The whole method is this:

private boolean validateDocs(List<Map<String, Object>> documentsList) {
  boolean isValid = true;
  StringBuilder gradoAntComp = new StringBuilder();
  for (Map<String, Object> document : documentsList) {
   String id = document.get("ID_DOC").toString();
   if (id.equalsIgnoreCase("25")) {
    isValid = getData(id.toString(),program().toString(), document.get(name))
   } else if (id.equalsIgnoreCase(REQ_ING) ) {
    isValid = isValid && getDocs(id.toString(),program().toString(), document.get(name));
   } 
  }
  return isValid;
 }

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58275312/edit) the post.

Comment: OK, so no, given your actual code, it's not redundant at all. If you removed it, a previously false isValid could become true again at the next iteration. With `isValid && ...`, isValid can only stay false once it becomes false. That said, the method should simply return false as soon as isValid becomes false instead of continuing to loop.

Comment: You don't need `id.toString()`: it's already a string, and you already know it's non-null.

Comment: Using `equalsIgnoreCase` with Strings that only contain digits seems a bit paranoid to me.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem the UK "government gateway" cards had (dunno if they still do) a numeric id, and said ["not case sensitive"](https://www.flickr.com/photos/126283859@N03/14691138041/) on them.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem but it fits into the rest of the code, like creating an entirely unused `StringBuilder` or calling `toString()` on `id` which is already a `String`, not to speak of the fact that the result of `id.toString()` is even known at compile time due to the preceding conditional. Unless, someone considers the fact that the code in both alternatives is identical, except for the `isValid = …` and `isValid = isValid && …` difference which looks much like a bug to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was redundant in your original question. The original method you posted could be reduced to:

```
public boolean aMethod() {
    return executeGetDocs(id.toString(),program().toString(), document.get(name));
}
```

since `(true && x) == x` for any `boolean` `x`.

However, since you changed the question, the answer changes as well. Now the `boolean` variable may change multiple times within a loop. Therefore it makes sense to AND the previous value of the variable (which may be `true` or `false`) with another `boolean`, which might cause its value to change.

```
private boolean validateDocs(List<Map<String, Object>> documentsList) {
    boolean isValid = true;
    StringBuilder gradoAntComp = new StringBuilder();
    for (Map<String, Object> document : documentsList) {
        String id = document.get("ID_DOC").toString();
        if (id.equalsIgnoreCase("25")) {
            // this can set isValid to either false or true
            isValid = getData(id.toString(),program().toString(), document.get(name))
        } else if (id.equalsIgnoreCase("26") ) {
            // therefore performing logical AND between the previous value of
            // isValid and some additional boolean is meaningful - isValid will
            // be assigned true only if it was true before this statement AND
            // getDocs(id.toString(),program().toString(), document.get(name)) is true
            isValid = isValid && getDocs(id.toString(),program().toString(), document.get(name));
        } 
    }
    return isValid;
}
```

Comment: Though this raises some questions. E.g. is it intentional that the result of evaluating a `"25"` id overwrites previous results or is the list expected to be sorted by id (and distinct), in which case the loop could break after encountering `"26"`? And should the absence of these specific ids truly be treated as “valid”? Or why does the method create that obsolete `StringBuilder` or calls `toString()` on objects that are already a `String` or uses `equalsIgnoreCase` instead of `equals` for *numbers*?

Answer (score 3):

Not that we see your entire method, we can see that you're attempting to assign to `isValid` within a loop.  Written this way, the code is using the `&&` conditional-and operator to only execute the method `getDocs` if `isValid` is still `true`.

If a previous assignment to `isValid` set it to `false`, then `getDocs` won't even be called; it will be short-circuited.  This means that the `&&` operator already knows that the result of the expression will be `false`, because `isValid` is `false`, so it "short-circuits" the evaluation and doesn't evaluate the other operand -- the call to `getDocs`.

This makes a lot of sense especially if `getDocs` is a method with a large overhead cost.

Answer (score 1):

As you initialize **isValid** as true it's useless you can rewrite it as:

```
public boolean aMethod(){
    return executeGetDocs(id.toString(),program().toString(), document.get(name));
}
```